# Not reading data from the array always displaying no preference

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, switch-statement

Hi all I am currently working on an iPhone application. 
The application is for a an estate agent, and the app reads information in from a feed. 
The client is able to have various options on the app which allows them to select a community then a sub community. 
Obviously I can't have all of the sub communities displayed in one go because they only exist in certain communities. So what i was trying to do was the following : 
 Here is a snippet of my code from the URL Query generator:  The following is for the community.

```
[urlString appendString:@"&Tier1_ID="];
            switch ([_appDelegate int_Tier1_ID]) {
                case 0: [urlString appendString:@"0"]; break;//No preference
                case 1: [urlString appendString:@"190"]; break;
                case 2: [urlString appendString:@"85"]; break;
                case 3: [urlString appendString:@"88"]; break;
                case 4: [urlString appendString:@"89"]; break;
```

And here is what i am trying to do in the URLQueryGenerator for the Sub community:

```
        [urlString appendString:@"&Tier2_ID="];
        switch ([_appDelegate int_Tier1_ID]) {

            case 0: [urlString appendString:@"0"]; break;

            case 1:switch (_appDelegate.int_Tier2_ID){
                case 0: [urlString appendString:@"0"];break;
            case 1: [urlString appendString:@"200"]; break;
            case 2: [urlString appendString:@"201"]; break;
            case 3: [urlString appendString:@"202"]; break;
            case 4: [urlString appendString:@"203"]; break;
            case 5: [urlString appendString:@"204"]; break;
            case 6: [urlString appendString:@"205"]; break;
            case 7: [urlString appendString:@"206"]; break;
            case 8: [urlString appendString:@"207"]; break;
            }break;

            case 2:switch (_appDelegate.int_Tier2_ID){
                case 0: [urlString appendString:@"0"];break;
                case 1: [urlString appendString:@"285"]; break;
                case 2: [urlString appendString:@"286"]; break;
                case 3: [urlString appendString:@"287"]; break;
                case 4: [urlString appendString:@"288"]; break;
                case 5: [urlString appendString:@"289"]; break;
                case 6: [urlString appendString:@"290"]; break;
                case 7: [urlString appendString:@"408"]; break;
                case 8: [urlString appendString:@"291"]; break;
                case 9: [urlString appendString:@"292"]; break;
                case 10: [urlString appendString:@"293"]; break;
                case 11: [urlString appendString:@"403"]; break;
                case 12: [urlString appendString:@"294"]; break;
                case 13: [urlString appendString:@"295"]; break;
                case 14: [urlString appendString:@"296"]; break;
                case 15: [urlString appendString:@"297"]; break;
                case 16: [urlString appendString:@"298"]; break;
                case 17: [urlString appendString:@"309"]; break;
                case 18: [urlString appendString:@"299"]; break;
                case 19: [urlString appendString:@"402"]; break;
                case 20: [urlString appendString:@"300"]; break;
                case 21: [urlString appendString:@"301"]; break;
                case 22: [urlString appendString:@"406"]; break;
                case 23: [urlString appendString:@"302"]; break;
                case 24: [urlString appendString:@"308"]; break;
                default:[urlString appendString:@"0"]; break;
            }break;
            default:[urlString appendString:@"0"]; break;
        }
```

Here is a snippet of the subcommuinity delegate:

```
FindPropertyAppDelegate  * _appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray* array;

    switch (_appDelegate.int_Tier1_ID) {
        case 0:
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     NSLocalizedString(@"No Preference", nil),

                     nil];
            break;
        case 1://DIFC
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     NSLocalizedString(@"No Preference", nil),
                     @"Central Park Tower",
                     @"Currency House",
                     @"DIFC",
                     @"DIFC",
                     @"DIFC Tower",
                     @"Emirates Financial Towers",
                     @"Gate Boulevard",
                     @"Park Towers",
                     @"The Gate Precint",
                     nil];
            break;
        case2://Dubai Marina
            array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     NSLocalizedString(@"No Preference", nil),
                     @"Al Atina",
                     @"Al Fattan Marine",
                     @"Al Majara",
                     @"Al Marjan Villas",
                     @"Al Sahab",
                     @"Bay Central",
```

However when i click on the picker it always only displays "No Preference".

The user should get the relevant results when they choose a community.

Can any one help I'm so confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your base problem is, your going to spin yourself into more trouble then you deserve by writing code this way. It's probably an anti-pattern to use `AppDelegate` as a dumping ground for just any random thing. And based on what little I can glean from your example, you should probably be creating a new class

```
@interface FeedInfo

// set these
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger tier1ID;    
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger tier2ID;

// and then get these
@property (readonly) NSString *urlString;
@property (readonly) NSArray *subCommunities;

@end
```

You could then break some of your multiple nested `switch` statements into single methods inside your implementation, which you can compose internally into your `urlString`.

If you learn the standards of how to program in Objective-C, you'll probably be saving yourself pain in the long run. I understand, that may not put the product in the hands of your client quickly (this time... possibly), but it will improve the quality of what they *do* get immensely.